# Asyncio attach identifier to coroutine within function throws exception

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I thought I figured everything out about asyncio I need to know but I am struggling with this one.

I need to run some url calls asynchronisouly but have an identifier in their return. This works by defining an async function but in my mind this should also work inline within the code but it doesn't and instead prints out `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required`

I have a (non-)working example attached, could someone point me in the right direction of my mental mistake?

Best Regards

```py
import httpx
import asyncio
from pprint import pprint

__search_url = 'https://1.1.1.1'

async def search_async(client, params, symbol):
    return await client.get(__search_url, params=params), symbol

async def get_async_works(symbol_list: list)->list:

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:

        tasks = []
        for symbol in symbol_list:
            params={'query': symbol}
            task = search_async(client,params={'query': symbol},symbol=symbol)
            tasks.append(task)


        reqs = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for req in reqs:
            pprint(req)

asyncio.run(get_async_works(['1', '2']))
# (<Response [200 OK]>, '1')
# (<Response [200 OK]>, '2')


async def get_async_doesnt_work(symbol_list: list)->list:

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:

        tasks = []
        for symbol in symbol_list:
            params={'query': symbol}
            task = (client.get(__search_url, params=params), symbol)
            tasks.append(task)

        reqs = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for req in reqs:
            pprint(req)


asyncio.run(get_async_doesnt_work(['1', '2']))
# TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
# sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncClient.get' was never awaited
```

Comment: In the `get_async_doesnt_work` function the `task` variable is a tuple.